Editor was remove after input when custom handlers React-quill
I use React-quill for my project
  <ReactQuill
    ref={quillRef}
    value={value}
    onChange={setValue}
    theme="snow"
    modules={{
      toolbar: {
        container: [
          [{ header: "1" }, { header: "2" }, { font: [] }],
          [{ size: [] }],
          ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike", "blockquote"],
          [
            { list: "ordered" },
            { list: "bullet" },
            { indent: "-1" },
            { indent: "+1" },
          ],
          ["link", "image", "video"],
          ["clean"],
        ],
        handlers: {
          image: () => {},
        },
      },
    }}
    formats={[
      "header",
      "font",
      "size",
      "bold",
      "italic",
      "underline",
      "strike",
      "blockquote",
      "list",
      "bullet",
      "indent",
      "link",
      "image",
      "video",
    ]}
  />

It have some custom handlers.
The problem is: When I type any charactor to ReactQuill, whole ReactQuill editor was removed from html DOM.
If I don't use any handlers
handlers: {

},

the error wont appear and every thing work well.
How can I fix this
